# secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN could be expired in github action?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a private image/repo used in my dependencies. Today, I pushed 3 times into my repo, first two times my action-ci showed install private dependencies success, but the last time is failed, the error is about access denied. I did not change anything from the setting or the code, I don't know why it gave me this error. I check the registry setting, I am 100% sure I gave the repo with full permission to install that private image/repo.
I think secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN could be expired? or what setting is wrong.

Thanks for any help.

```
run: login
 username: ${{ GitHub.actor }}
 password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
 registry: ghcr.io
run: npm ci
 env: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: `ghrc.io` -> `ghcr.io` Quite an often misspelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[The GITHUB_TOKEN in GitHub Actions: How it Works](https://dev.to/github/the-githubtoken-in-github-actions-how-it-works-change-permissions-customizations-3cgp)" (from [Davide 'CoderDave' Benvegnù](https://dev.to/n3wt0n)), GitHub automatically creates a `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret for you to use in your workflow, and you can use it to authenticate in a workflow run.

That means it should <del>not "expire"</del> during the execution of the very workflow it was created for authentication.
As noted by [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643738/secrets-github-token-could-be-expired-in-github-action#comment130059598_73644353), if your individual action takes [more than 24 hours](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) to complete... the token would actually expire.

> Before each job begins, GitHub fetches an installation access token for the job.
> The `GITHUB_TOKEN` expires when a job finishes or after a maximum of 24 hours.

Check first if the issue persists later on today.

There was a [significant outage yesterday](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/pz0bvrjx9ztp) which did impacted GitHub Action execution.

Comment: Github action back to work at this morning. so weird. Thanks your help

Comment: _"That means it should not "expire" during the execution of the very workflow it was created for authentication."_ - it does though, after six hours. When your individual actions run that long, you have other problems though. Edit edit edit: [it's 24 hours now](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

Comment: @CodeCaster Good point, than you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Hence my personal rule of thumb of waiting at least a day after an outage for things to get back to normal, and a whole week if it's a big outage... :-)